# Constantly getting expected spy setDateRestrictions have been called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-test

I have written below method in my .ts file.

```
setDateRestrictions() {
    if (moment(this.form.get('startDate').value).isValid()) {
        const sDate = this.form.get('startDate');
        const eDate = this.form.get('endDate');
        eDate.enable();
        this.minEndDate = (moment(sDate.value) > moment() ? moment(sDate.value) : moment()).format(this.dateFormat);
        if (moment(eDate.value).isValid() && moment(sDate.value).isAfter(moment(eDate.value))) {
            eDate.reset();
        }
    } else {
        this.form.get('endDate').reset();
        this.form.get('endDate').disable();
    }
}
```

This method is called inside ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isReadOnly = !this.authHelper.canCreateUpdateDeleteAtPage(this.permissionUri);
    this.currentUser = this.commonService.getCurrentUsername();
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.questionnaireKey = params['questionnaireKey'];
        this.isClone = this.router.url.includes('clone');
        this.isEdit = this.router.url.includes('edit');

      const observable = Observable.forkJoin(
        this.questionnaireKey ? this.surveysService.getSurvey(this.questionnaireKey) : Observable.of(null),
        this.surveysService.getSurveyImages());
      observable.subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp[1]) {
          this.images = resp[1];
        }

        if (this.questionnaireKey) {
          this.adminSurvey = resp[0];
          this.initializeEditForm();
        } else {
          this.buildNewForm();
        }
        this.setDateRestrictions();
        this.openQuestionnaireFields(false);
      });

    });

}
```

I have written test case in spec.ts file as below.

```
    describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const surveyServiceStub: SurveyService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        SurveyService
      );
      const communicationSuiteCommonServiceServiceStub: CommunicationSuiteCommonServiceService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        CommunicationSuiteCommonServiceService
      );
      const authHelperServiceStub: AuthHelperService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        AuthHelperService
      );
      spyOn(component, 'setDateRestrictions').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(surveyServiceStub, 'getSurvey').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(surveyServiceStub, 'getSurveyImages').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(
        communicationSuiteCommonServiceServiceStub,
        'getCurrentUsername'
      ).and.callThrough();
      spyOn(
        authHelperServiceStub,
        'canCreateUpdateDeleteAtPage'
      ).and.callThrough();
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.setDateRestrictions).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(surveyServiceStub.getSurvey).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(surveyServiceStub.getSurveyImages).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(
        communicationSuiteCommonServiceServiceStub.getCurrentUsername
      ).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(
        authHelperServiceStub.canCreateUpdateDeleteAtPage
      ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

It is throwing error

> Expected spy setDateRestrictions to have been called.

From HTML it is called like this

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="input-lable" for="startDate">Work Start Date</label>
  <input class="unstyled form-control" onkeydown="return false" ng-required="true"
       formControlName="startDate" type="date" (change)="setDateRestrictions()" />
</div>
```

Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your `ngOnInit` method?

Comment: @David Updated my question with ngOninit code.

Comment: Is it because the observables `getSurvey` / `getImages`haven't completed yet when you test that the method has been called?